# Java ArrayOutOfBoundException in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

The question is Define a cluster in an integer array to be a maximum sequence of elements that are all the same value. For example, in the array `{3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4}` there are 5 clusters, `{3, 3, 3}`, `{4, 4}`, `{3}`, `{2, 2, 2, 2}` and `{4}`. A cluster-compression of an array replaces each cluster with the number that is repeated in the cluster. So, the cluster compression of the previous array would be `{3, 4, 3, 2, 4}`. The first cluster `{3, 3, 3}` is replaced by a single 3, and so on.

```
public static void  main(String[] args) {

    int[] givenArray = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    System.out.println("Clustered Array = " + Arrays.toString(isTrivalent(givenArray)));
}

public static int[] isTrivalent  (int[] a){

    List<Integer> cluster = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=0; i<a.length ; i++ ) {

        if(i == 0){
            cluster.add(a[i]);
        }else{
            if(cluster.get(i-1) != a[i]) cluster.add(a[i]);
        }
    }

    int[] arr = new int[cluster.size()];

    for (int j =0; j<cluster.size() ; j++) {
        arr[j] = cluster.get(j);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

But I am getting an `ArrayOutOfBoundException`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: What do you want to do with this line of code `if(cluster.get(i-1) != a[i]) cluster.add(a[i]);`

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
if(cluster.get(i-1) != a[i]) cluster.add(a[i]);
```

to

```
if(a[i-1] != a[i]) cluster.add(a[i]);
```

`cluster.get(i-1)` may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you check

```
if(cluster.get(i-1) != a[i])
```

it is not necessary that the cluster arraylist will actually have size of atleast `i-1` since you are skipping a lot of array elements. You need to change your condition to

```
if(cluster.get(cluster.size()-1) != a[i])
```

or equivalently (as suggested in previous answer)

```
if(a[i-1] != a[i])
```

for this code to work as intended.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] givenArray = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    System.out.println("Clustered Array = " + Arrays.toString(isTrivalent(givenArray)));
}

public static int[] isTrivalent(int[] a) {
    List<Integer> cluster = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            cluster.add(a[i]);
        } else {
            if (cluster.get(cluster.size() - 1) != a[i]) {
                cluster.add(a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    int[] arr = new int[cluster.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < cluster.size(); j++) {
        arr[j] = cluster.get(j);
    }
    return arr;
}
```